# Is this normal behaviour for pycuda's gpuarray.dot() function?

Tags: python, numpy, pycuda

Pycuda's gpuarray.dot() operation does not do the same thing as numpy.dot() operation. Is this on purpose?

For example, the code below does a numpy.dot() then gpuarray.dot(). The former returns a 5x5 array and the latter a single number.

```
import numpy as np
import pycuda.autoinit
import pycuda.gpuarray as gpuarray
np.random.seed(1)

print ("\nNUMPY: result of np.dot - OK")
a = np.array(2 * np.random.random((5, 5)) - 1)
b = np.array(2 * np.random.random((5, 5)) - 1)
a_b_dot = np.dot(a, b)
print (type(a_b_dot), a_b_dot.shape)
print (a_b_dot)

print ("\nPYCUDA: result of gpuarray.dot - NOT OK")
a_gpu = gpuarray.to_gpu(a)
b_gpu = gpuarray.to_gpu(b)
a_b_dot = gpuarray.dot(a_gpu, b_gpu)
print (type(a_b_dot), a_b_dot.shape)
print (a_b_dot)
```

**The output is:**

```
NUMPY: result of np.dot - OK
<class 'numpy.ndarray'> (5, 5)
[[-0.4289689  -1.07826831  0.35264673  1.17316284  0.37989478]
 [-0.23539466  0.62140658  0.02890465  0.64194572 -0.90554719]
 [ 0.6308665  -0.5418927   0.15072667  1.53949101 -0.17648109]
 [-0.28165967 -1.06345895  0.17784186 -0.50902276  1.27061422]
 [ 0.15769648  0.01993701 -0.42621895 -0.07254009 -0.23463897]]

PYCUDA: result of gpuarray.dot - NOT OK
<class 'pycuda.gpuarray.GPUArray'> ()
-0.3611777016515303
```

Comment: This, somewhat old, thread, http://pycuda.2962900.n2.nabble.com/PyCUDA-gpuarray-dot-question-td7574909.html says that `gpuarray.dot` is just the vector dot product, resulting in a scalar.  `np.dot` does that with 1d arrays too, but you are using it for 2d matrix multiplication.

Comment: Wow, that's from 2012. If that's still true today I would be surprised, since I thought np.dot() is quite a common operation. Unless, the answer is that a GPU can't do this operation faster so it need not be implemented.

Comment: https://andreask.cs.illinois.edu/PyCuda/Examples/MatrixmulSimple -

Comment: Thanks. It's true, I used a square matrix in my example but I need this for non-square matrices.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the reason why pycuda does this is because it would require pycuda to either have a dependency on cusparse/cublas (so it doesn't have to re-implement this stuff). The simplest way of extending this is to apply dot product across the entire thing and let the end user go and find their own matrix multiply library if they need something more advanced.

If you actually want a dot product on matrix this way, you just use a matrix multiply, see the following example for proof:

```
import numpy as np

print("\nNUMPY: result of np.dot - OK")
a = np.array(2 * np.random.random((5, 5)) - 1)
b = np.array(2 * np.random.random((5, 5)) - 1)
a_b_dot = np.dot(a, b)
a_mul_b = np.matmul(a, b)
print(type(a_b_dot), a_b_dot.shape)
print(a_b_dot)

print(type(a_mul_b), a_mul_b.shape)
print(a_mul_b)

NUMPY: result of np.dot - OK
<class 'numpy.ndarray'> (5, 5)
[[-0.12441477 -0.28175903  0.36632673  0.35687491 -0.25773564]
 [-0.57845471 -0.4097741   0.3505651  -0.23822489  1.17375904]
 [-0.19920533 -0.43918224  0.62438656  0.6326451  -0.27798801]
 [ 0.67128494  0.44472894 -0.57700879 -0.57246653 -0.0336262 ]
 [ 0.49149948 -0.65774616  1.09320886  0.76179777 -0.76590202]]
<class 'numpy.ndarray'> (5, 5)
[[-0.12441477 -0.28175903  0.36632673  0.35687491 -0.25773564]
 [-0.57845471 -0.4097741   0.3505651  -0.23822489  1.17375904]
 [-0.19920533 -0.43918224  0.62438656  0.6326451  -0.27798801]
 [ 0.67128494  0.44472894 -0.57700879 -0.57246653 -0.0336262 ]
 [ 0.49149948 -0.65774616  1.09320886  0.76179777 -0.76590202]]
```

To do true matrix multiply you will either A: need to implement your own, or B: use scikit cuda (which both depends on pycuda and interops with it).

In scikit cuda this is pretty much the [same as numpy](https://scikit-cuda.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/skcuda.linalg.dot.html#skcuda.linalg.dot) (ripped straight from scikit cuda docs)

```
>>> import pycuda.autoinit
>>> import pycuda.gpuarray as gpuarray
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import skcuda.linalg as linalg
>>> import skcuda.misc as misc
>>> linalg.init()
>>> a = np.asarray(np.random.rand(4, 2), np.float32)
>>> b = np.asarray(np.random.rand(2, 2), np.float32)
>>> a_gpu = gpuarray.to_gpu(a)
>>> b_gpu = gpuarray.to_gpu(b)
>>> c_gpu = linalg.dot(a_gpu, b_gpu)
>>> np.allclose(np.dot(a, b), c_gpu.get())
True
>>> d = np.asarray(np.random.rand(5), np.float32)
>>> e = np.asarray(np.random.rand(5), np.float32)
>>> d_gpu = gpuarray.to_gpu(d)
>>> e_gpu = gpuarray.to_gpu(e)
>>> f = linalg.dot(d_gpu, e_gpu)
>>> np.allclose(np.dot(d, e), f)
True
```

Under the hood with scipy, you are using a cuda dll back end that converts things into ctypes and such, and you'll notice a lot lower level primitives for multiplication than numpy (sticking with 2 dimensions in most cases). If you do happen to need to use multiply matrix multiplies in a nd matrix, they will still be 2d, but you can do them in batch with your backends batch function, or [mdot](https://scikit-cuda.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/skcuda.linalg.mdot.html#skcuda.linalg.mdot)